# Displaying main report with subreport

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, subreport

The following is my code and it is working with only one report.

```
rptbill = New CrystalReport1
rptexp = New ExpensesReport
rptmain = New MAINREPORT

rptbill.SetDataSource(dtincom)
rptexp.SetDataSource(dtexp)
frmCrystalReport.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptmain
```

What I want is that my `rptmain` shows the field of my submenus `rptbill` and `rptexp`. I don't know how to get this to work.

Comment: Have you linked sub report with main report

Comment: thank you for the reply but i solve the problem. all i need is to bind all the subreport to the main report. with a lucky search in google i found a great article about this matter.